# There are lots of bad questions out there. Is the rep reward for asking good questions too low?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, reputation

I'm sure this has been suggested a zillion times over the years, but it seems that as the SO community grows, it's become a lot harder to find a good question than it is to find a good answer.  Shouldn't the rep awarded for good questions be heavier than the rep for good answers?

Comment: You realize that increasing the rep gained from question upvotes will cause more people to ask more bad questions.  Especially given that lots of bad questions do actually attract upvotes.

Comment: The problem is much more that bad questions still provide reputation too often.

Comment: I don't think that bad question askers are going to post better questions if the rep is higher. I would be more inclined to think that the rep **loss** for downvotes on bad questions would be more of an incentive.

Comment: @codeMagic how so?  Most of the people that ask a bad question have a rep of 100 or less.  They don't have a whole lot to lose.

Comment: It's not going to matter. Even though 99% of the questions are terrible, the vast majority of them come from help vampires. Help vampires don't give a sh1t about rep. They just want their question answered. My guess is that most of them ask 1 or 2 questions before leaving or getting banned and they don't come back. But there are so many new users that, it just keeps coming. It's like fighting an advancing army that has infinite troops. No matter how many you kill, they keep on coming.

Comment: @Servy why not make the penalty for bad questions more severe as well?

Comment: I'm not sure that it would do *much* good. I think the solution is elsewhere. But I think that losing more rep would do more good than increasing rep.

Comment: I don't think reputation rewards are what people asking the vast majority of bad questions are after. They just want an answer to a question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I expect that to be true of most people asking questions *period*, good or bad.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Because lots of people are very hesitant to actually downvote content, even very bad content, but *especially* content that is pretty bad, but not god awful.  "Fairly poor" questions tend to have a positive, not negative, score.

Comment: @Servy I think that's mostly true. I suspect that reputation rewards might provide a little bit of incentive to ask a *higher-quality* question, but asking the question to begin with starts with needing an answer.

Comment: I don't know.  It's been so long since I upvoted a question, I cannot remember how much rep gets awarded:(

Comment: @Mysticial http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211493/165773

Comment: Related, given that it proposes the opposite and was actually implemented: [Should the weight of question upvotes be reduced?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42769)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The motivation for bad questions isn't reputation, it's Stack Overflow having a high Google rank. The people dumping their poorly researched, do-my-work-for-me questions here are doing so because they're desperate for an answer.

They won't put any more work into their questions if we gave them 100 points per upvote or 1. They don't bother to look at other questions, and won't even care if those other questions are getting answers. They're just going to shove their terrible questions into whatever text box appears first, and Stack Overflow is currently at the top of the search results.

Stack Exchange has actually [reduced question reputation](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/) over time because of the way people shotgunned borderline questions just to farm reputation. That was lowering question quality, so I don't think going back to that would help.

Comment: Hmm that seems completely counterintuitive to me.

Comment: *"after casting 300 votes, you cannot downvote non community wiki posts at more than a 2:1 ratio"* is that based on your all time votes, or is it a moving target based on a recent time period. It's going to suck if i someday can't downvote anymore without upvoting because i've reached that mark...

Comment: @KevinB Are you responding to a deleted comment?  You aren't prevented from downvoting if you have a 2:1 downvote:upvote ratio.  Just look at, say, Eric Lippert.  His ratio is...higher than that.  So's mine, for that matter (although not by nearly as much).

Comment: @Servy I'm referring to the blog post linked in the answer. It surprised me, because i'm positive that my ratio is worse than that on average, If i keep going like i am i'll hit 2:1 some time next year

Comment: @KevinB It has clearly been removed at some point since then.  No idea when, but it must have been quite some time ago.

Comment: @BradLarson In light of the recent policy change to increase rep for upvoted questions (https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers), I'm interested in your take.  Has your opinion changed at all in the last 4 years?  Do you think this change is a good or bad thing?